# Preventing date stamps from being included in org mode exports

Tags: export, org-mode

When exporting from Org Mode (via Spacemacs) to LaTeX (or HTML) I can't seem to prevent date stamps from being included in the exported file.

I have `(setq org-export-with-timestamps nil)` in .spacemacs and in the document (top level) I have the following...

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil num:nil <:nil
```

Seems like I've covered my bases, but when the file is exported both active and inactive date stamps are included. Have I missed a switch somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with the

```
#OPTIONS: <:nil
```

line and I get no timestamps (active, inactive, scheduled, deadline) in either the PDF or HTML output. This is with

Org-mode version 8.3.2 (release_8.3.2-253-g9b5757)

Perhaps update and try again?